# A bug on perl interpreter on error message?

Tags: perl

When I run the following code to check the error message, perl (5.14.2 on Ubuntu) says 
`Illegal division by zero at test2.pl line 5.`

```
sub dummy   { 
    if ($a>3) {
        $a ++;
    }
    else { printf(1/0);
    }
    return 1;
}
dummy();
```

However, if I remove the space in front of `printf`, the error message will say
`Illegal division by zero at test2.pl line 2.`

Removal of the extra space should not change the line number in the error message here.
So it appears that it's a bug on the perl interpreter.  Is this right?

Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed on Win7 Strawberry Perl v5.16.2.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @TLP.

Comment: Confirmed on Centos 6.5, Perl v5.10.1.

Comment: Confirmed in 5.20.0.

Comment: Does not happen with 5.8.8

Comment: Thanks guys for confirming it. I am sure all the info can be used to help tracking down when the bug got it.

Comment: Funny coincidence, this bug was mentioned [earlier today](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2014/09/msg219269.html) on the p5p mailing list. Interestingly, the incorrect "fallback" line for the `printf` is the spot of the earlier `Use of uninitialized value $a in numeric gt (>) at test.pl line 2.` warning. The `__LINE__` token seems to be affected too: [[1](https://eval.in/187861)] [[2](https://eval.in/187863)]

Comment: Thanks @Slade for pointing it out. Glad it's being looked at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, it's a bug. You can let the Perl devs know using command line tool `perlbug`.

Comment: Thanks, will report it as you suggested.